# How to launch a subprocess in the background and stop it by pressing a key?

Tags: python, keyboard, subprocess

I am on Windows 10, using Python 3.7, and want to launch a subprocess to read a video and stop it if the user is touching the keyboard (I'm using the `keyboard` module from https://pypi.org/project/keyboard):

```
import subprocess
import keyboard

p1 = subprocess.call(keyboard.record(until='enter'))
p2 = subprocess.call([vlc, url_video, "vlc://quit", "&", "exit 0"])
while True:
    if p1.poll():
        p2.terminate()
        break
    if p2.poll() == None:
        break
```

The problem is that launching `p1` doesn't return, and is blocking the launch of `p2`. So I never enter the infinite loop.

Comment: You would have to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) must help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems with this code:

- `subprocess.call(keyboard.record(until='enter'))` first calls `keyboard.record` which blocks until it returns, and *then* calls `subprocess.call` with the return value of `keyboard.record` as argument (which doesn't make sense in itself).
- [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) also blocks until the launched subprocess finishes (besides not doing what you want here, it is also outdated since Python 3.5.). We can use `subprocess.Popen` to launch a subprocess in the *background*.

You are not using the [`keyboard` API](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api) effectively. You do not want to [*record*](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.record) the keystrokes while the video recording is running, you want to *trigger an action* if a specific key is pressed. For this, the [`on_press_key`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardon_press_keykey-callback-suppressfalse) function seems to be suitable.

It takes function (a *callback*) which will be executed once a specific key is pressed. We can pass a function which will terminate the subprocess we have launched.

As far as I can tell, this should work:

```
import subprocess
import keyboard

# I haven't checked if these arguments are correct, they are unchanged
p = subprocess.Popen([vlc, url_video, "vlc://quit", "&", "exit 0"])

# set up callback to kill vlc if key is pressed
def stop_vlc(event):
    if p.poll() is not None:
        return  # already done, do nothing
    p.terminate()

keyboard.on_press_key('enter', stop_vlc)

# wait until vlc finishes, either by itself or because it is killed
p.wait()
```